# Reputation inaccuracy between SO profile and actual SE site (TeX.SE)

Tags: support, status-bydesign, reputation, profile-page

Pretty simple - My profile page on SO is off by 5 reputation when compared to the actual value on the TeX.SE site:

[image: Profile Page Summary (left) is different from actual value (right)]

Obviously it's an insignificant amount, but perhaps it's not so insignificant for another user?

Comment: Give it a few - it'll sync up.

Comment: It's just a caching issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long live the caching - as stated just wait a few minutes.